# How to test a moving server

Tags: apache, server

I am migrating server because of CentOs upgrade (from 5 to 6).

Old server still runs www.myDomain.com (primary DNS points to 'old' IP)

All web and databases content are already copied to the new server. Web content is in /home/myDomain/public_html

I own myTestDomain.com and set DNS in new server for it (Primary NS in new server).

What's the simplest way to check myDomain.com behavior on new server using myTestDomain.com ? (httpd.conf, alias)

*Edit*

I started to set

```
SuexecUserGroup "#528" "#519"
ServerName myTestDomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/myDomain/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/myTestDomain.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/myTestDomain.com_access_log combined
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.php4 index.php5 index.html.var
```

Web page started to display as expected.
Is there any set I should have to add for security?

Answer (score 0):

Entries in `/etc/hosts` usually take precedence over DNS resolution, so you can talk to the new server on its new IP with the name `www.mydomain.com` without having a DNS entry for that, so you don't have to mess with the configuration you copy from the old server. The line would look something like

```
10.66.66.66  www.mydomain.com
```

if 10.66.66.66 is the IP of the new server. If your server does funny things like talking to itself by its name, the new server itself might need an entry in `/etc/hosts` for its faked name, too, so it doesn't accidentally talk to the productive system.

Comment: I didn't change any DNS record for myDomain.com but the primary at domain registrar to point to the old still working server. myTestDomain.com points to the new server where also is myDomain.com data in /home/myDomain/public_html.  
myTestDomain.com has its web home page (nothing here) in /home/myTestDomain/public_html (until I changed DocumentRoot in httpd.conf. Adding that line to /etc/hosts does not take action to home page.  At this time I've solved that in that way detailed in my question